# Node.JS Application - Tasks and API

Tags: node.js, api, task, command-line-interface

General question.

I am looking to create a console-like application with Node.js that also has api capabilities. It will have timed task that will run on a schedule but also be available to send http request to. My problem is that while I've created the api. I don't know how to go about creating basic task to be performed on a schedule while the server stays running in case http request is made for different types of task.

**Main idea is to have the task schedule to run while also keeping the server running and waiting for http request**

**Folder paths**

> *folders*
>   -controllers
>   -models
>   -modules
>   -node-modules
>   -routes
>   *general files*
>   app.js
>   package-lock.json
>   package.json
>   server.js
>   task.js

*Proposed area for Scheduled task to be performed:*
**index.js**

```js
    const { checkTablesForData, requestRoutine, runNecessaryUpdate }  = require('./task')

    function Main() {
        ...
        \\task to be executed

        \\Check the table for records to be processed
        let obj = checkTablesForData();

        \\Send third party request with object data. ie - id's
        obj.map( id => {
            \\call request routine
            requestRoutine(id)
        })

        \\Run final process
         runNecessaryUpdate(id)
    }
```

**task.js**

```js
    checkTablesForData(){
        ...
    }

    requestRoutine(id){
        ...
    }

    runNecessaryUpdate(id){
        ...
    }

    module.exports = { runNecessaryUpdate, checkTablesForData, requestRoutine }
```

*Code for api setup*

**app.js**

```js
    const express = require('express')
    const path = require('path')
    const app = express() //, api = express();
    const cors = require('cors');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.redirect('./api')
    })

    const api = require('./routes/api');
    app.use('/api', api)

    module.exports = app
```

**server.js**

```js
    const app = require('./app');

    const port = process.env.PORT  || 3000;

    app.listen(port, 'localhost', () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);

    });
```

**api.js**

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

    //Controller Modules
    const controller = require('../controllers/homeController');

    //Routes
    router.get('/request/:id', controller.post)



    module.exports = router;
```

**controller.js**

```js
    //Send request to 3rd party api
    export.post = function(req, res){
        const options = {
            ....
        }

        return request(options)
        .then( response => {
            ...
        }
        .catch( error => {
            \\error routine
        }
    }
```

Advice is very much needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you don't show any code or describe these tasks in any way, all we can really say is that you would generally use `setTimeout()` to schedule a task to run sometime in the future.  And you would set up an http server to respond to your  API  requests.  Not sure what else you expect us to come up with given how little information you've provided.

Comment: It was meant to be a general question but i will set up some information to give an idea.

Comment: This site proves much more useful with specifics including code and thorough descriptions of what you're trying to do than broad general, non-specific questions.

Comment: Tasks can be run in the same process (if they aren't CPU heavy and are coded with non-blocking I/O) or they can be run in a WorkerThread or their own process, depending upon needs.

Comment: Updated post with description, code examples, and folder structure.

Comment: https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/

Comment: What are the tasks?  What do they do?  Why not just use `setTimeout()` to schedule your tasks to run at the appointed time in the future?  I'm really not sure what else you're asking beyond that.  A server in node.js stays up and running and able to accept requests even though you're running some other tasks in node.js as long as the tasks doesn't block the event loop for too long with heavy CPU intensive stuff or blocking I/O calls (the one's that end in "Sync").  As long as the tasks are good citizens, you can likely run them just fine along with your server and both will be happy.

Comment: If your task is heavy CPU, then run it in a [WorkerThread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

Comment: I added some vague tasks up top to help create the bigger picture. I guess i'm more or less uncertain of how to set it up to start the server and run the setTimeout(). IE if i ran this in production how would i force server to start and the get the setTimeout() task running.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  `server.listen(...)` starts your server.  `setTimeout(someCallbackFunction, someTimeValue)` schedules a callback to be called some number of milliseconds into the future.  You just call these two things and your server starts the timer is set.  That's all there is to it.  The node.js process can do multiple things like this.  It can listen for incoming requests on your server and it can manage timers to call some callback at some future time.